# How do I solve for $m$ and $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

While reading about nested radicals, I came across a theorem that said $\sqrt{m\sqrt[3]{4m-8n}+n\sqrt[3]{4m+n}}=\pm\frac {1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{(4m+n)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{4(4m+n)(n-2n)}+\sqrt[3]{(n-2n)^{2}}\right)$

So I tried an easy example ($\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}$) and got this System of Equation: $$\begin{cases}m^3(4m-8n)=-4\\n^3(4m+n)=5\end{cases}\text{or} \begin{cases}m^3(4m-8n)=5\\n^3(4m+n)=-4\end{cases}$$

My question: How do I solve for $m$ and $n$ without too much tedious work, and how do I know which System to discard?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that $4$ and $5$ can even be written in this form with $m$ and $n$ "nice"?

Comment: Yes, because Ramanujan already proved that $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}=\frac {1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{25}-\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$ :D

Comment: @Frank Actually minus that, although I agree you might have been thinking of the negative square root!

Comment: Did you double check your system of equations ? Works much better with $-4$ in the first RHS.

Comment: It does... I have changed the original post to adding in the $-4$! (Not factorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate $m$ from the first system with

$$m=\frac{5-n^4}{4n^3},$$

giving

$$(5-n^4)^3(20-36n^4)=1024n^{12},$$

a quartic equation in $n^4$

$$9(n^4)^4-396(n^4)^3+750(n^4)^2-1500(n^4)+625=0.$$

---

Even Wolfram cannot find a closed-form solution !

---

With $-4$ in the RHS of the first equation, the equation is

$$9(n^4)^4+116(n^4)^3+750(n^4)^2-1500(n^4)+625=0,$$

which has the root $n^4=1$.

Comment: There is a formula for quartic equations..

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: I know, and so does Wolfram. Casus irreductibilis ?

Answer (score 1):

$$m^{3}(4m-8n)=4=m^4(4-8\frac{n}{m})$$
similarly 
$$n^4(4\frac{m}{n}+1)=5$$ 
now let $\frac{m}{n}=t$
,therefore 
$$m^4(4-\frac{8}{t})=4...(1)$$
and $$n^4(4t+1)=5...(2)$$
now divide both equations $(1) \& (2)$ to have a equation solely in $t$ and after solving for $t$ you can get $m$ and $n$. as far as solution to choose , choose whichever gives you a postive answer as square root cannot be negative 
(p.s this is tedious but the only approach i could think of)

Comment: I'm kind of confused by what you mean by divide both equations. Divide both by what? (This approach is way easier than my approach... substituting is just a nightmare)

Comment: the final two equations i got , divide the r.h.s of both equations and equate it by division of the l.h.s , you would have gotten rid of $m$ and $n$ and equation will fully be in form of $t$

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks!

Comment: t.b.h just try simple guesses first for these type of questions , $m$ and $n$ equal to -1 satisfy the equations

Comment: @avz2611: too good to be true.

Comment: @Yves Daoust , i did not get you?

Comment: @avz2611: your simple guess was wrong... until I warned the OP and he fixed his formulas.

Comment: My only problem with trying simple guesses is that what if $m=24$ and $n=10$? It would probably take a really long time.

Comment: @frank thats very true , but atleast we can try and get the basic ones out of the way before going on to solving harder ones. There maybe many scenarios where in general an equation may not be analytically solvable but have a very simple answer . Thus when equations look ugly , try a few guesses and if your not able to get the answer try and solve them

Comment: With a different generalized formula, I have found: $$\sqrt{3\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{13}}=\frac {1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{169}+\sqrt[3]{52}-\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$$